# Routing design in Spray

Tags: scala, rest, routes, spray

I'm trying to make a rest service for profile management. So i have the following uri for profiles:

```
host/profile/id123123/:action
```

But there are different profile types, for different users with different dashboards, so i want to extract `profileType` and `id` as the top path and work with different actions under this. I've tried to write it in DRY way:

```
path(Segment / "id" ~ Segment) { (profileType, id) ⇒
  get {
    profileType match {
      case "admin" ⇒ loadProfilePage[Admin](id)
    }
  } ~
  path("update") {
    complete("Profile updated")
  }
}
```

But if i type the following in the address bar:

```
localhost/admin/id123123/update
```

It throws server exception. What's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have wrong routing structure. If you want have different logic for different paths under some common one, in your case `path(Segment / "id" ~ Segment)`, then you need to use `pathPrefix` directive. Then the right route would look like this:

```
pathPrefix(Segment / "id" ~ Segment) { (profileType, id) ⇒
  path("") {
    get {
      profileType match {
        case "admin" ⇒ loadProfilePage[Admin](id)
      }
    }
  } ~
  path("update") {
    complete("Profile updated")
  }
}
```

But still early extraction not a very good thing, if you have a very complex route structure this will slow down the overall performance, not much, but your inner route, after extraction point, gonna be evaluated dynamically.

**Update**

I just though of a little optimisation. I think that you are going to have not only `update` path bu others too. So in this case that would be cleaner to make the following route:

```
pathPrefix(Segment / "id" ~ Segment) { (profileType, id) ⇒
  (get | put) {
    profileType match {
      case "user" ⇒
        path("")(loadProfilePage[User](id)) ~
        path("update")(updateProfile[User](id)) ~
        path("delete")(deleteProfile[User](id)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Still that's not a perfect way, i would generalize it further, cause the only thing, as i understand, that would change is `profileType`